# Yocto - read-only-rootfs - unable to remount as RW on .hddimg

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded, yocto-wic

So we have a yocto warrior 2.7.1 system.  Converting from an EOL board based on an ancient yocto to a newer one.

I have the following added to make rootfs RO.

`IMAGE_FEATURES += " read-only-rootfs"`

We have a very small handful of times when we need to do this:

`mount -o remount,rw /`

and of course revert back to RO.

The thing is that w/ the .hddimg it fails with

`mount: /: cannot remount /dev/root read-write, is write-protected.`

Of course the .wic image works fine, but unfortunately I can't use the .wic image for this project.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Extra info:
Removing read-only-rootfs from the features then simply changing the fstab entry to ro from default in meta/base-files like below works, but creates other issues.

```
/dev/root            /                    auto       ro            1  1
```

Comment: I was able to sort this out actually by removing read-only-rootfs and making a bbappend file for base-files.  My earlier comment that it caused issues was incorrect.  It all works fine.